# Gstreamer 0.10 switch the output-selector through keyboard

Tags: gstreamer

I am using gstreamer 0.10 version.
My usecase is with two branches (tee element). In one of them I have   ->decoder->tee->jpegenc->output-selector->fakesink
                                        ->multifilesink

This is  implemented in application. Now I am switching  between the both outputs with g_timeout_add but in this case if it is connected 10s to the fakesink it is connected same time to the multifilesink. I want to archive: if I press a button to save only one frame as jpg. If I press it again I should save it under different name(that is why I am using multifilesink, the filesink will overwrite it). Could someone helps me with tips please how can I archive this with the event from the keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

First, 0.10 is years obsolete and unmantained, please consider moving to 1.0 versions.

This is more a case of looking how to read chars from the console. You can use getchar() or use GIOChannel as you might also need a mainloop for your application (https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-IO-Channels.html#g-io-channel-read-chars). An example of using GIOChannel. One example application can be found here: https://github.com/thiagoss/gst-test-apps/blob/master/apps/dvbsrc-capture-freq-switch.c (though it waits to read a whole line but you can modify to suit your needs).

Another advice I'd give on your pipeline is to have the output-selector before the jpegenc to avoid encoding images just to discard. Also, it might be easier to achieve what you want by using a buffer pad probe that would return FALSE to drop the buffer or TRUE to let it pass in 0.10 or the _DROP and _OK returns in 1.0 (go for 1.0!). It will be easier than using an output-selector for your case.

Comment: Any example how to use this buffer pad probe and to control it with keyboard event with gstreamer 0.10?

Comment: http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/chapter-dataaccess.html#section-using-probes in 1.0 (as I recommend you using) or refer to http://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/docs/latest/gstreamer-0.10/GstPad.html#gst-pad-add-data-probe for the outdated API. The documentation contains examples and my reply above contains an example of using GIOChannel to read keyboard (reading full lines). When you write your code you can share it here for future reference of other people.

Comment: In fact,  now I am able to unlink and link the filesink element, when the pipeline is in PLAYING state without a problem on 0.10. I removed the output-selector in this case I just do not need it. Thank you for the help. I met other problem how I could check the src buffer contains a full frame ? This way I could check for I frame  but I need any frame do not care is it I . (GST_BUFFER_FLAG_IS_SET(buffer, GST_BUFFER_FLAG_DELTA_UNIT)) 
  {
    return FALSE;
  }
  else if (!GST_BUFFER_FLAG_IS_SET(buffer, GST_BUFFER_FLAG_IN_CAPS)) 
  {
    return TRUE;
  }